# Getting Exception when trying to upload a big files size

Tags: c#, wcf, large-files, payload

I'm using wshttpbinding for my service

```
<wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="wsHttpBinding_Windows" maxBufferPoolSize="9223372036854775807" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
                <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
                <security mode="Message">
                    <message clientCredentialType="Windows"/>
                </security>
            </binding>
        </wsHttpBinding>

<behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
                <dataContractSerializer  maxItemsInObjectGraph="6553600"/>
                <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="2147483647" maxConcurrentInstances="2147483647" maxConcurrentSessions="2147483647"/>
            </behavior>
```

and when i try to upload a file of 15Mb it throws the EndPointNotFoundException below:

Exception Message:

```
There was no endpoint listening at "MY SERVICE URL" that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.
```

Exception:

```
The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
```

Comment: Does it work if you upload smaller sized files?

Comment: Verify the IP address and the port of the endpoint in the `<endpoint>` section

Comment: yes, it uploads smaller size. There is a one more thing that i'm using async calls (if it matters.)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are (2) settings `maxRequestLength` and `maxAllowedContentLength` on the server side in your WCF confgiration that you are going to need to increase in order for this exception to be resolved. In the .config for the WCF service server side make sure to add the following:

```
<system.web>
  <!--Increase 'maxRequestLength' to needed value: 100mb (value is in kilobytes)-->
  <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="102400"/>
</system.web>

<system.webServer>
  <security>
    <requestFiltering>
      <!--Increase 'maxAllowedContentLength' to needed value: 100mb (value is in bytes)-->
      <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="104857600" />
    </requestFiltering>
  </security>
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 1):

The upload limit is set at 2 level, 1st by the Application and 2nd by the Server.

Your app configuration looks good to me.

Check your IIS settings as defined in your machine.config file.
I found a [Microsoft KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/295626)  to configure this

You can configure the  value at any of these places.