# WCF error - There was no endpoint listening at

Tags: c#, wcf

I am developing a WCF service, running IIS6 on Window server 2003. I have built a test client to talk to the WCF service and I am getting the error below. I have been looking at this error for days and went through people's suggestions on forums, but with no luck. Any help would be appreciated, many thanks

> There was no endpoint listening at
>   https://webbooking.infodata.uk.com/Synxis/Synxis.svc that could accept
>   the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP
>   action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.

```
System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
  at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)

Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ProcessGetResponseWebException(WebException webException, HttpWebRequest request, HttpAbortReason abortReason)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at IOta2010A.ReservationSynch_SubmitRequest(ReservationSynchRequest request)
   at Ota2010AClient.IOta2010A.ReservationSynch_SubmitRequest(ReservationSynchRequest request) in c:\Development\WorkingFolder\Webservices\SynxisNew\App_Code\OTA2010A.cs:line 57589
   at Ota2010AClient.ReservationSynch_SubmitRequest(Security Security, DateTime& TimeStamp, String CorrelationID, String RelatesToCorrelationID, ReplyTo ReplyTo, OTA_HotelResNotifRQ OTA_HotelResNotifRQ) in c:\Development\WorkingFolder\Webservices\SynxisNew\App_Code\OTA2010A.cs:line 57601
   at Update.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Development\WorkingFolder\Webservices\SynxisNew\Update.aspx.cs:line 72
```

**Client config**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="ota2010AEndpoint" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
                receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" bypassProxyOnLocal="false"
                transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true"
                allowCookies="false">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                    maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
                    enabled="false" />
                <security mode="Transport">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                        realm="" />
                    <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true"
                        establishSecurityContext="true" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </wsHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="https://webbooking.infodata.uk.com/synxis/synxis.svc"
                binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ota2010AEndpoint"
                contract="IOta2010A" name="ota2010AEndpoint" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

**Service config**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="Pervasive.Data.SqlClient, Version=2.10.0.34, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=C84CD5C63851E072"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <authentication mode="Windows"/>
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID"/> 
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="Synxis" behaviorConfiguration="SynxisWCF">
        <endpoint address="" name="wsHttpEndpoint"  binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="Synxis" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <diagnostics>
      <messageLogging logEntireMessage="true" logMalformedMessages="true"
         logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true" logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true"
         maxMessagesToLog="300" />
    </diagnostics>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="SynxisWCF" >
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" externalMetadataLocation="https://webbooking.infodata.uk.com/synxis/Synxis.svc.wsdl" />
            <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: What do you see when you open the service URL directly from the browser?

Comment: When I open the service URL link, I see the "You have created a service" page, as expected.

Comment: In your service config you have an endpoint elements whose contract attribute value is just the class/interface name whereas it should be a fully qualified name i.e namespace.Synxis

Comment: Thanks Rajesh for your comment. The reason why contract attribute is just the class name is because there is no namespace. I assume this is not a big deal?!

Comment: Are you able to navigate to any http (not https) service, if you have one? I had faced similar issue and realized later that .svc extension were missing from IIS metabase. Had to re-register the framework. Namespace could be another reason as Rajesh mentioned.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I also had the .svc extension problem much earlier on, but am sure it was giving out another error message. Anyhow, Tim's answer below has fixed my problem

Comment: @NeilHung - As an aside, are you including too much internal information in your question? I would suggest using domains like example.com and other arbitrary values rather than exposing internals. This could plague you in the future. Edit your question with the changes and then flag it for a moderator to delete the revision with sensitive data.

Comment: I was getting the same error with a service access. It was working in browser, but wasnt working when I try to access it in my asp.net/c# application. I changed application pool from appPoolIdentity to NetworkService, and it start working. Seems like a permission issue to me.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You do not define a binding in your service's config, so you are getting the default values for `wsHttpBinding`, and the default value for `securityMode\transport` for that binding is `Message`.

Try copying your binding configuration from the client's config to your service config and assign that binding to the endpoint via the `bindingConfiguration` attribute:

```xml
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="ota2010AEndpoint" 
             .......>
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" ... />
        <reliableSession ordered="true" .... />
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                       realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true"
                     establishSecurityContext="true" />
          </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

(Snipped parts of the config to save space in the answer).

```xml
<service name="Synxis" behaviorConfiguration="SynxisWCF">
    <endpoint address="" name="wsHttpEndpoint" 
              binding="wsHttpBinding" 
              bindingConfiguration="ota2010AEndpoint"
              contract="Synxis" />
```

This will then assign your defined binding (with Transport security) to the endpoint.

Comment: This is the solution to my problem! Thanks!

Comment: I test your solution for my problem but I don't get answer!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38856971/wcf-http-binding

Comment: My mistake was the address attribute, it had a value different of empty. Removing the value made the work.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. For me I noticed that the https is using another Certificate which was invalid in terms of expiration date. Not sure why it happened. I changed the Https port number and a new self signed cert. WCFtestClinet could connect to the server via HTTPS!

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error with a service access. It was working in browser, but wasnt working when I try to access it in my asp.net/c# application. I changed application pool from appPoolIdentity to NetworkService, and it start working. Seems like a permission issue to me.

Answer (score 1):

in my case

my service has function to `Upload Files`

and this error just shown up on trying to upload `Big Files`

so I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13361847/4251431) to Increase `maxRequestLength` to needed value in `web.config`

and problem solved

if you don't make any upload or download operations maybe this answer will not help you

Comment: before vote down,,,do you have upload or download operations?

Answer (score 1):

Different case but may help someone:

In my case, the Windows firewall was enabled on the Server.

Either of these two things can be done:

- Disable the Windows firewall (at your own risk, but it will get things work).
- Add the port in an inbound rule.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the issue  by clearing value of address in endpoint tag in web.config:

```
<endpoint address="" name="wsHttpEndpoint"  .......           />
```