# WCF returns 404 for large request, maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"

Tags: wcf

Our WCF service on large request returns following error:

*"System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException: There was no endpoint listening at http://xxx.svc that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.*

For small requests everything works fine and I am getting correct response from WCF service, the issue is only with large requests.

Settings on the client are as follow:

```
 <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ITestService" openTimeout="00:05:00" sendTimeout="00:05:00" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" >
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
            maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:33333/TestService.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ITestService" contract="TestService.ITestService" name="BasicHttpBinding_ITestService" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

The settings of the WCF service:

```
 <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483646" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
```

What can be the issue?

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17572500/wcf-error-there-was-no-endpoint-listening-at

Comment: I had the settings provided on above question.

Answer (score 15):

In this case, the error was not with WCF but with the IIS settings. 
The Message was to large for IIS, I have added "**maxAllowedContentLength**"  to the web.config on the server.

```
<system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2200000000"/>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
```

The error message was misleading.

Comment: @DamienPawski how did you figure that out?

Comment: For people like me who tend to prefer the GUI, you can find this option under `IIS Manager -> Sites -> Configuration Editor` as well

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was not working even after trying all solutions and setting all limits to max. In last I found out that a Microsoft IIS filtering module [Url Scan 3.1](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/urlscan) was installed on IIS/website, which have it's own limit to reject incoming requests based on content size and return "404 Not found page".

It's limit can be updated in `%windir%\System32\inetsrv\urlscan\UrlScan.ini` file by setting `MaxAllowedContentLength` to the required value.

For eg. following will allow upto 300 mb requests

MaxAllowedContentLength=314572800