# WCF error "there was no endpoint listening at ..."

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm creating my first WCF app. Client can communicate with host when those are on same computer, but failed from other computer on LAN. Both are console app.

Here is my code and config.

Client config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
   <system.serviceModel>
      <bindings>
         <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="WSHttpBinding_ICalculator" />
         </wsHttpBinding>
      </bindings>
      <client>
         <endpoint name="WSHttpBinding_ICalculator"
             address="http://192.168.100.6:8000/ServiceModelSamples/Service/CalculatorService"
             binding="wsHttpBinding" 
             bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_ICalculator"
             contract="ServiceReference1.ICalculator">
             <identity>
                <userPrincipalName value="saumitra\skpaul" />
             </identity>
         </endpoint>
      </client>
   </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Host code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Step 1 Create a URI to serve as the base address.
        Uri baseAddress = new Uri("http://Localhost:8000/ServiceModelSamples/Service");

        // Step 2 Create a ServiceHost instance
        ServiceHost selfHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(CalculatorService), baseAddress);

        try
        {
            // Step 3 Add a service endpoint.
            selfHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ICalculator), new WSHttpBinding(), "CalculatorService");

            // Step 4 Enable metadata exchange.
            ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
            smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
            selfHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);

            // Step 5 Start the service.
            selfHost.Open();
            Console.WriteLine("The service is ready.");
            Console.WriteLine("Press <ENTER> to terminate service.");
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.ReadLine();

            // Close the ServiceHostBase to shutdown the service.
            selfHost.Close();
        }
        catch (CommunicationException ce)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("An exception occurred: {0}", ce.Message);
            selfHost.Abort();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This sounds like a job for ... Firewall Man :-)

Comment: Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: Yes, change the firewall rules to allow incoming sessions to the specific port. But that's not really a programming question so much as one that should be over on ServerFault. You'll get "better" answers over there.

Comment: What happens when you try to browse http://192.168.100.6:8000/ServiceModelSamples/Service/CalculatorService from client?

Comment: @Amit It says "the webpage is not available"

Comment: Then you have connectivity issues. Solve those. Check for firewall setting for server and client and also check do you have  <userPrincipalName value="saumitra\skpaul" />
on server as a valid user?

Comment: saumitra\skpaul is a valid user

Comment: possible duplicate of [WCF error - There was no endpoint listening at](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17572500/wcf-error-there-was-no-endpoint-listening-at)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get an idea from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17572500/wcf-error-there-was-no-endpoint-listening-at)

You can also use Socket Programming. [Here](http://aviadezra.blogspot.com/2008/07/code-sample-net-sockets-multiple.html) is a very good example for mutli-client, two-way communication socket programming.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Those articles are really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

First ensure that the address used from the client is the correct location of the server. Your code is currently hard coded to the destination as...

```
<endpoint address="http://192.168.100.6:8000/
```

...but is the server actually running on 192.168.100.6?

Comment: Host is running as a console app on 192.168.100.6 and client is also a console app running on 192.168.100.7.

Comment: Try running the WCF Client on the client machine to see if you can actually connect to the server address. https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/workandstudybook/archive/2014/06/03/standalone-wcftestclient.aspx