# Updating Service References for specific endpoint

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, wcf-rest

My server used to communicate only with WCF client, and I added an additional access from the web using REST API. So currently the service's web.config contains two endpoints (one for each):

```
 <services>
  <service name="Server.Service">
    <endpoint address="" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IServWCF" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="Server.IWCF" />
    <endpoint address="api" behaviorConfiguration="WebBehave" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="Server.IREST" />
  </service>
</services>
```

The WCF client bindings:

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IServWCF" />
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://localhost:1862/ServWCF.svc"
    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IServWCF"
    contract="WCFServ.IWCF" name="BasicHttpBinding_IServWCF" />
</client>
```

Everything works OK, and I can access the server's methods from both ways - WCF and HTTP requests.
The problem - I tried to use the Update Service References feature, but it fails. I get the following error message:

> The client and service bindings may be mismatched. the remote server returned an error 415

When I remove the new endpoint - behaviorConfiguration="WebBehave", the update service reference works fine. Can I somehow configure the Update References to use a specific end point?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WCF error - There was no endpoint listening at](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17572500/wcf-error-there-was-no-endpoint-listening-at)

Comment: Please, publish bindings section.

Comment: Type service url in the browser to see more details regarding the issue. Svc util doesn't say much about errors.

Comment: I tried that and now I get the error"the client and service bindings may be mismatched". Any ideas? @ShakirAhamed

Comment: check the contract of both client and server side config it should be with project name contract="Server.IREST"   here Server is your project name??/

Comment: Does your service implement two service contracts?