# The provided URI scheme 'https' is invalid; expected 'http'. Parameter name: via in developement

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ssl, wsdl

I'm getting this error when trying to call a function of a `wsdl`. I added a `ServiceReference` to a project in my solution. In that project I have the following `app.config` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="MYSERVICENAME_ws_Authorization_Binder" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
                useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                <security mode="Transport">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" proxyCredentialType="Basic"
                        realm="" />
                    <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="MYSERVICEURL"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="MYSERVICENAME_ws_Authorization_Binder"
            contract="MYSERVICE.Authorization_PortType" name="MYSERVICENAME_ws_Authorization_Port" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
<system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
        <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging">
            <listeners>
                <add name="messages"
                type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
                initializeData="c:\logs\messages.svclog" />
            </listeners>
        </source>
    </sources>
</system.diagnostics>
<system.serviceModel>
    <diagnostics>
        <messageLogging
             logEntireMessage="true"
             logMalformedMessages="true"
             logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true"
             logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true"
             maxMessagesToLog="3000"
             maxSizeOfMessageToLog="2000"/>
    </diagnostics>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Then in my main project, the `MVC` project I have the following in the `Web.config` file.

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="MYSERVICENAME_ws_Authorization_Binder" />
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="MYSERVICEURL"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="MYSERVICENAME_ws_Authorization_Binder"
            contract="MYSERVICE.Authorization_PortType" name="MYSERVICENAME_ws_Authorization_Port" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

The error occurs when I'm running in debug mode, `localhost`. I haven't tried it on my website since I'm still developing. My website has a certified `SSL` and my localhost is also configured to run on `HTTPS` but only with a self-signed certificate.

Am I getting this error because my self-signed certificate isn't enough? Can I make `localhost` also use the `SSL` that my website is using? If not, what's the best solution to this? I have found a few posts on this error but haven't found a solution that helps me yet.

Comment: Sounds like the endpoint address isn't `https` for your service reference.

Comment: Try putting in your `wsdl` address into WCF Test Client `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio {your VS version}\Common7\IDE\WcfTestClient.exe`.

Comment: Ok, I found another URL that I'm probably supposed to use and it's ´https´ but now I get the error "There was no endpoint listening at MYURL that could accept the message..." I have looked this error up but never found a solution to this either.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17572500/wcf-error-there-was-no-endpoint-listening-at#17577881 Maybe that'll help

Comment: Thanks a lot for your responses. I found another way to work with this service, via Nuget package and that was a lot easier. I still don't know why the other way didn't work.