# There was no endpoint listening at “http://…” that could accept the message

Tags: c#, soap

When I try to access the URL http://... using code in C#, I am getting the error

> "There was no endpoint listening at http://.. that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details."

But when I try to launch the URL directly from IE, it is working fine. what could be the reason ?

Comment: Could be that the domain only accepts HTTP**S** requests

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WCF error - There was no endpoint listening at](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17572500/wcf-error-there-was-no-endpoint-listening-at)